# eje y con datos de tiempo y sufijo

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sigo peleándome con los datos temporales.

Tengo un df de este estilo:

```
id_atleta   Ritmo_min   Rendimiento
JEV 0:04:14 Excelente
MAI 0:04:50 Excelente
MLB 0:05:38 Por encima de la media
MGP 0:05:38 Por encima de la media
ATP 0:03:59 Excelente
DGR 0:06:46 En la media
CAR 0:05:38 Por encima de la media
JPO 0:04:50 Excelente
```

Genero un gráfico de la siguiente forma:

```
g_ritmo <- ggplot(df, aes(x = id_atleta, y = Ritmo_min, fill = Rendimiento)) + geom_col() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'), plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', color = NA), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'), legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', color = NA), legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12), legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 14)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7986CB", "#4DB6AC", "#CE93D8", "#FFECB3", "#FF8A65")) + scale_y_time(breaks = seq(0, 420, by = 30), labels = scales::label_time(format = %M:%S"))
```

Y obtengo el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es añadir en el eje de las *y* el sufijo " min/km". Pero no lo consigo con nada de lo que estoy probando.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, yo transformaría `Ritmo_min` en un dato más adecuado para `ggplot`:

```
df <- read.table(text='id_atleta   Ritmo_min   Rendimiento
JEV 0:04:14 "Excelente"
MAI 0:04:50 "Excelente"
MLB 0:05:38 "Por encima de la media"
MGP 0:05:38 "Por encima de la media"
ATP 0:03:59 "Excelente"
DGR 0:06:46 "En la media"
CAR 0:05:38 "Por encima de la media"
JPO 0:04:50 "Excelente"', header=T, quote='"')

df$Ritmo_min <- as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", df$Ritmo_min), 
                           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                           tz = "UTC")
```

Con esto tenemos un `POSIXct` con el tiempo en minutos y segundos, ahora simplemente hay que establecer el formato de la etiqueta:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = id_atleta, y = Ritmo_min, fill = Rendimiento)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7986CB", "#4DB6AC", 
                               "#CE93D8", "#FFECB3", "#FF8A65")) +
  scale_y_time(breaks = seq(0, 420, by = 30), 
               labels = scales::label_time(format = "%M:%S min/km"))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: maemía! sí que era simple. Gracias. Yo estaba intentando algo más complicado. Sí, la variable ritmo_min la transformo previamente con as_hms() y la redondeo a segundos con round_hms(). No sé si es equivalente a lo que me propones tú. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo es añadiendo `ylab("min/km")` al código con el que generas el gráfico.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).